# Cellular communications queuing

Tags: signal, wireless, digital-communications, signal-theory

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but this is a homework question.

> Consider a base station in a cellular network. The base station has the resources to handle 7 calls at the same time. The call inter-arrival times and the durations of calls are both exponentially distributed. A base station may get calls due to handoffs (with rate \$\lambda_H\$ or from users in its own coverage area (with rate \$\lambda_O\$. Assume a priority based handoff scheme where 2 of the servers are kept aside only for handover calls.

Consider the situation where $$\lambda_H = 0$$ and average call length is 3 minutes.

**My solution**

Form up the queue system and solving this.

$$\mu = \frac{1}{3}$$

$$P_o = \left[\sum_{i=0}^{n=5} {\left(\frac{\lambda_H + \lambda _O}{\mu}\right)}^i \frac{1}{i!} + \sum_{i=6}^{n=7} {\left(\frac{\lambda_H}{\mu}\right)}^i \frac{1}{5!} \frac{1}{(5^{i-5})}\right]^{-1}$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n=7} P_i = 1$$

However, I am stuck since it goes up to a power of 5.

Comment: So what is your question about this question? If you want us to comment on your answer, you might want to show some of your thought process.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes i was posting my question to update the parts. As a lot of latex is involved and i dont have a preview so i have to post it and update afterwards